# How to persist from multiple forms with one button?

Tags: java, forms, jsf, primefaces

I have two forms, an one button.

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="Form Name: *" />
    <p:inputText required="true" value="#{currentTemplate.name}" />
</h:form>
```

and one button in another form.

```
<h:form id="orderListForm">
    <p:commandButton value="Submit"
    action="#{orderListBean.callPersist}" style="margin-top:5px"
    id="btnCitySubmit" />
</h:form>
```

I want to save the value from the first form with the second.

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: iirc the "easiest" approach to this problem is to write an `onSubmit`-handler and copy the values of one form to hidden fields of the other form. Submitting two forms does not work

Comment: @MarcoForberg pls give a concret example for your possible solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to execute all inputs in both forms? Then `process="@all"` attribute of `<p:commandButton>` is for you. It will process *all inputs within a page*.

Alternatively, you can specify ids of components to be processed, like `process="@form :another-form"`, if to-be-updated form has `id="another-form"` specified.

Comment: ok thx for your answer! however, i have the button in a form itself and I get an exception that the button could not be called the form.